# MFP connection getting error in ios

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I am unable to connect MFP in ios i'm getting the error like this.

```
Response Data: /*-secure-{"reason":"App authenticity security check failed"}*/ 
2016-10-10 10:53:56.293 appname[3983:433885] [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLAuthorizationManager failRegistratioWithResponse:] in WLAuthorizationManager.m:846 :: Response does
 not contain a valid certificate and client Id. device registration failed
2016-10-10 10:53:56.295 appname[3983:433885] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager removeKey:] in WLCertManager.m:261 :: Key was successfully remove
```

MFP version 7.1.0.00.20150807-0630

Comment: Will you be so kind to also mention your MobileFirst Platform version...?

Comment: this is the version i'm using "x-wl-platform-version" = "7.1.0.00.20150807-0630";

Answer (score 4):

1. Upgrade your server and studio installations to the latest iFix release from IBM Fix Central, currently at 7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201610060540 as many authenticity-related issues have been resolved
2. Authenticity errors may happen if you incorrectly setup authenticity

   - You forgot to add the bundleId and applicationId to the application-descriptor.xml file
   - You're using a different bundleId value than your actual bundleId value for the iOS application

For instructions: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/authentication-security/application-authenticity-protection/

Comment: bundleId="CIMBWallet" this is the bundle id in application-descriptor.xml and my actual bundle id is com.xyz.xyz

Comment: As the documentation states, if your bundleId is "com.xyz.xyz", you also need to set the descriptor elements the same way: `<iphone bundleId="com.xyz.xyz" applicationId="xyz"`

Comment: <nativeIOSApp applicationId="CIMBWallet" bundleId="com.xyz.xyz" id="CIMBWallet" platformVersion="7.1.0.00.20150807-0630" version="4.7" xmlns="http://www.worklight.com/native-ios-descriptor"> but still i'm getting failure responce

Comment: You're not supposed to actually put "xyz"! Use YOUR BUNDLEID. com.your-company-name.your-bundleId.

Comment: Use Wireshark to inspect the network traffic when the failure occurs and provide the log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125308/discussion-between-manchikanti-krishnakishore-and-idan-adar).

Comment: That's not Wireshark. Wireshark is software you install on the same machine your server is and inspect the network traffic. In addition to Wireshark, also update your installation to the iFix level I've mentioned.